# IN ODI12c mapping expression execute on source in LKM without "execute on source hint"

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

IN ODI12c mapping, we can use "execute on source hint" for mapping expression  in order to execute expression on source. Is there a way to get mapping expression (no matter what the execution hint is) in LKM?
When i use [EXPRESSION] in LKM, it get only expressions with "execute on source hint".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

You need to understand the next points.
You could generate the expressions in IKM, put them into a variable and then use it in LKM.

This can be done because the execution order is the next:

All the KM's have sections:

- Mapping Begin, Execution Unit Begin, Execution Unit Main, Exection Unit End, Mapping End;
- Each of this section is executed in the next order: Mapping Begin from LKM then Mapping Begin from IKM then Execution Unit Begin from LKM then Mapping Begin from IKM and so on.
- the last section of each KM - Mapping Cleanup - is executed as above, but only if Mapping > Physical > Check "Remove Temporary Objects on Error"

In other words, you could do it like this:

- declare a variable that use `[EXPRESSION]` in section Mapping Begin in IKM;
- use that variable in LKM in one of the next sections (not Mapping Begin).